# Get real windows directory of mounted directory in MSYS (or use ln with MSYS)

Tags: windows, bash, msys, ln, mklink

I have an MSYS installation, and I am writing a bash script to set up some files. I would like to make a directory symbolic link from the bash script in MSYS, but to do that I will need to use `mklink /D`, which is a windows command. `ln` does not work with NTFS symbolic links, it only seems to copy the folder, so I cannot use that unfortunately.

I have a directory mounted as `/opt` in MSYS using fstab. The real directory is `C:\opt` (but it could be anything)

`mklink` expects a Windows-style path like `C:\opt`. However, I can only provide `/opt` which it cannot work with. Is there any way to get the "real" path of `/opt`?

Alternatively, if there's a way to get `ln` to work like `mklink /D` that'll be great. But I can't seem to find a way (there does exist a way in Cygwin however but it didn't seem to work for me)

Note: I do not have cygwin, and I do not want to install external software (including cygwin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out somehow, although it is kinda an ugly hack

If I want to figure out the real Windows path of the current directory, I can used `pwd -W`, which is apparently an MSYS-only feature

In my script, I can probably do something like:

```
realpath=`cd /opt && pwd -W`
```

to get the real path of /opt. I tested it and it seems to work.

I'd appreciate a less ugly method though

Comment: I think you don't need the `cd -` at the end because the whole thing runs in a subshell anyway. So that makes it very slightly less ugly. :P

Comment: That prints `C:/blah/opt`. Any way to get it to output backslashes (`C:\blah\opt`)?

Comment: @rustyx  You can pipe to sed. So something like
`realpath=\`cd /opt && pwd -W | sed s/\\//\``

I could not test this anymore though as I stopped using MinGW

Answer (score 1):

I call this "winpath" and stick it in my /usr/bin folder for msys.   Only `pwd` seems to support revealing the underlying rooted path:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
    dir=$(dirname "$1")
    add=/$(basename "$1")
else
    dir="$1"
    add=""
fi

pushd $dir > /dev/null
echo $(pwd -W)$add
popd > /dev/null
```